# How to extract a part of url from dictionary value in Python?

Tags: python, regex

I have a dictionary where the key's value is

`https://service-dmn1-region.com/info 4169 description`

I'm interested in fetching dmn1-region from that URL part and print 4169 description as it is. So I intend to print result as:

> dmn1-region :4169 description

Do you think it's possible without complex regex/regular expression. The script is in python and tried this -

`import re
 print re.sub('https://','',dictionary[key])`

This just removes https:// part and shows result as `service-dmn1-region.com/info 4169 description` . But I'm not sure how to achieve the above intended way.

key-value pairs from dictionary looks like-

```
dictionary = {'service': 'https://service-dmn1-region.com/info 4169 description',
'service1': 'https://service1-dmn2-region2.com/info 5123 someDescription','service2': 'https://dmn1-region-service2.com/info'}
```

Any insights and help very much appreciated.

Comment: Could you add more examples of the keys of the dictionary?

Comment: @DanielMesejo keys are just the project names.

Comment: Well more example of the project names. Do all the projects name start with service and end in region?

Comment: @DanielMesejo I put at the end of description.

Comment: The dictionary item **value** is `https://service-dmn1-region.com/info 4169 description` and the **key** is **service**,  **service1**, not the other way around.

Comment: @PedroLobito yes the key names are part of url domain. Also, the endpoint of all URLs  are same /info but their domain/regions  are different for each key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the information and the fact that you don't want to use regular expressions, you could do something like this:

```
dictionary = {'service': 'https://service-dmn1-region.com/info 4169 description',
              'service1': 'https://service1-dmn2-region2.com/info 5123 someDescription'}


def extract(key, s):
    info = '/info'
    service = key + '-'
    return s[s.find('service') + len(service):s.find('.com')], s[s.find(info) + len(info):].strip()


for key, value in dictionary.items():
    region, info = extract(key, value)
    print('{0}:{1}'.format(region, info))
```

**Output**

```
dmn2-region2:5123 someDescription
dmn1-region:4169 description
```

Note that the urls are the *values* of the dictionary and not the *keys*.

Comment: Thanks @Daniel this seems to be working as expected. But i think the issue would be what if there r 2 urls in the same dictionary value. For eg:  for service key, value is something like: 
'https://service-dmn1-region.com/info 4169 description https://service-dmn11-region11.com/info' 3232 someDescription'

Comment: You could split on spaces and match the element on the dmnX-region.com part. When it does match you'll have your region element and you know that the next 2 entries are the next part of the equation so you can then assign and afterwards increment your loop index variable accordingly making the next element to match a region one again.

Comment: @SoC don't forget to mark accepted answers where applicable: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 1):

I'd use something like:

```
import re
for k, v in dictionary.items(): # .iteritems() for py2
    print(re.sub(r"^.*?{}-([^.]+).*?(\d+)\s(.*?)$".format(k), r"\1 :\2 \3", v))
```

---

```
dmn1-region :4169 description
dmn2-region2 :5123 someDescription
```

[DEMO](https://ideone.com/bL4PiO)

Answer (score 0):

for values of the type `https://service-dmn1-region.com/info 4169 description`

you could just match on `^[^-]+-([^.]+)[^\s]+ (.*)$`

```
[harald@localhost ~]$ python3
Python 3.6.6 (default, Jul 19 2018, 14:25:17) 
[GCC 8.1.1 20180712 (Red Hat 8.1.1-5)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import re
>>> val = 'https://service-dmn1-region.com/info 
4169 description'
>>> res = re.match('^[^-]+-([^.]+)[^\s]+ (.*)$', val)
>>> res.group(1)
'dmn1-region'
>>> res.group(2)
'4169 description'
```

where `^[^-]+` matches from the start of the input (initial `^`) anything that isn't an apostrophe `-` (`[^-]+`), so `https://service`

next you specify that there must be one apostrophe to follow `^[⁻]+-` and that you wish to capture
everything that follows next that isn't a dot with `([^.]+)`. (as you guessed by now, precluding your pattern with ^ negates it and the pattern is written inside brackets [].

Leading us to `^[^-]+-([^.]+)`, next you wish ignore everything up to the next whitespace since that seperates the other values from the string so you add a pattern match for anything not whitespace (\s) leading to an extra `[^\s]+`, so `^[^-]+-([^.]+)[^\s]+`

which you then wish to follow up by the whitespace seperator (if expect more than 1 whitespace you could use `\s*` instead of an actual space) and you add a final catch-all capture pattern `(.*)`, which would capture `4169 description` (the dot stands for all characters here) until the end of the input `$` leading you to `^[^-]+-([^.]+)[^\s]+ (.*)$`.